# Htaccess mod rewrite rule for category

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like display content on *domain.com/something/aaa* with the url of *domain.com/something-else/aaa*. So when user clicks on *domain.com/something-else/aaa*, it will see the content at *domain.com/something/aaa*, but there are no redirect.

I need a rewrite rule to solve this without redirection. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Simple, use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^something-else/(.*$) /something/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Actually `RewriteRule ^something-else/(.*)$ /something/$1 [L]`